# Can I test a pointer for it's data type?

Tags: data-structures, if-statement, casting, compare, gstreamer

I have a gstreamer plugin with two inputs, and only one function to process them. one of the inputs is a char*, and the other is a struct

Is there a way to test the data type of the input buffer?

Something like:

```
chain_function(GstBuffer)
{
   if(GST_BUFFER_DATA(buffer) is mystruct)
      do something... 
   elseif(GST_BUFFER_DATA(buffer) is char*)
      do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's c++ you could use **[dynamic_cast](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/typecasting/dynamiccast.html)** if they share a common hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I have never actually used gstreamer; but from the [documentation of GstBuffer](http://developer.gnome.org/gstreamer/unstable/gstreamer-GstBuffer.html), I guess the functions to use are `gst_buffer_set_qdata()` and `gst_buffer_get_qdata()` to set and get meta-data on a GstBuffer.
You would then assign meta-data on each respective GstBuffer that represents the type and then in your function retrieve the meta-data and match these to be of its respective data type.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of data are you feeding to the plugin? Anyway, as it has been pointed out already, you will receive GstBuffer objects on your inputs (pads). Each GstBuffer had the actual data + metadata. Metadata is e.g. timestamp and duration, but also the caps. The caps describe the dataformat. You can check the caps to know how to handle the data that was sent.

If you want to send something that is not one of the already defined formats (like audio/video/text), you need to set own caps, e.g. "application/x-". It might be a good idea to describe what you want to do, as this is rarely needed.